# UICollectionView Horizontal Scroll with tableview layout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am creating a UICollectionView which scrolls horizontally.I have added a tableview inside the collectionViewcell.
The only problem that I am facing that the collectionViewcell width is not visible on full screen.

I used below code for collectionviewcell width and hight.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
```

My Gole is that a horizontal collection view that contains tableview in each cell.As you can see below image.

[image]